# How to map attributes WP ALL IMPORT

Tags: xml, wordpress, import

Hi there. Hope you are well!
I have an XML feed with products, and all attributes for each product are divided by the delimiter `|` as follows.

```
<attributes>
    Colour:Blue|Size:M|Type:Shirt|Weight:150gr
</attributes>
```

How can I import it using wp all import module for woocommerce?

And it’s important: every product attribute is ordered differently, so for 1 product colour it’s first, for another colour attribute is last in a row.
Thanks on advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At Step 3 of the All Import wizard, there is a Function Editor:
[image]

There is an example as part of the documentation, which is similar to what you need and which displays how to create such a custom function and then use it when declaring the attribute names and values. I tested it myself and it works:
https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/code-snippets/#split-by-index

The problem now is this requirement that you set: "*every product attribute is ordered differently*" which doesn't map to the above logic, which is more deterministic in terms of the order of the attributes.

The next question is: Do all the products that you want to import have these 4 attributes ? If yes, then in this case, you could run some XSLT transformation on your XML file in order to sort the attributes by name, so that for each product they show up in this order: Color, Size, Type, Weight and then import the transformed XML file.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion.
Some products have 10 attributes and more, they are totally different for categories types. 
I'll try to check if this https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/import/custom-code/foreach-loops/#:~:text=WP%20All%20Import%20supports%20a,that%20require%20a%20specific%20format. will help me.
Thanks